# Linking non-object file at a particular address

Tags: gcc, linker

Is there any option in GNU linker or linker script to load a non-object file at a particular address (i.e. the non-object file should be part of the executable image output by linker) ? Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Kiran

Comment: What do you mean by a "non-object file"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define a separate segment for your additional file and then set the address for that segment using `ld -segaddr`.

`$ man ld`